# How to get instagram username from username ID without API in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to find a way to get instagram username from the username ID in Python.
What I found so far is this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[USER-ID]?access_token=[YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN]
```

I have a token number, but it only works for users added to sandbox. For other users I receive the following error:

```
{"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "APINotFoundError", "error_message": "this user does not exist"}}
```

I'm searching a solution for hours with no luck so far. 
Is there a way to arrive to the same result without using a token?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why a down-vote???

Answer (score 6):

In my case I am getting data from tagFeed so I have picture code. If you have picture code of any of user's post then you can get username like this

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/picCODE/?__a=1

example: https://www.instagram.com/p/BaGce-NlMg7/?__a=1
```

it will return a JSON with the owner - username

Answer (score 5):

Point your browser to https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/USERID/info/ (replace USERID by the user id). It returns a JSON in which the field user.username is that user's username. With curl and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed, this shell oneliner will directly return the username:

```
curl -s https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/USERID/info/ | jq -r .user.username
```

Alternatively, the [Instaloader package](https://instaloader.github.io/) provides a convenient way to obtain a username given its ID, without using the official Instagram API.

```
import instaloader

L = instaloader.Instaloader()
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_id(L.context, ID)
print(profile.username)
```

It works by querying one of the profile's posts (for which only the profile's ID is required), obtaining that post's metadata (instagram.com/p/SHORTCODE) and then returning the `owner.username` value of that post.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can't. You need a token with `public_content` permissions, and for that, you need to have a live app (not in sandbox).